# Normal is the most difficult" -- origin in Japanese?

Tags: meaning, translation, etymology, daily-life, proverbs

I'm looking for the Japanese origin of the saying

> Normal is the most difficult.

I believe the longhand version would be

> Normality in life is the most difficult state/condition to attain/sustain.

Any idea what the original in Japanese may be?

I've heard this sentence in English many times from a Japanese person from Nagasaki area (Kyushu), so I guess it was a translation of a Japanese saying or a proverb. Would be great to know what the original sounds/reads like.

Answer (score 2):

I often hear such a phrase like 当たり前のことが一番難しい, which roughly says "Ordinary things are the most difficult (to do)".

I don't know if it is a fixed saying, as I searched Google I found many variations in wording e.g. 「当たり前が～」「～ことをするのが～」「当たり前のことを当たり前にやる（の／こと）が～」「当たり前のことほど～」 and so on. It seems considered to be a witty quote so that is printed on [a novelty T-shirt](http://www.oreryu-souhonke.jp/SHOP/4573185319947.html).

Some attribute this to [a famous pâtissier](http://meigen.ko2ko2.net/2009/05/0142.html), but to be honest I doubt he is the real inventor of this phrase.